# How to get input type text data from front-end search page in jsf2

Tags: jsf-2

I'm with a little problem in my search form because all of the data that I enter in the search fields are passing with null value to my java code.
I'm new to jsf2.

This is my xhtml page, with the form:

```
<h:form>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h:outputLabel for="equipmentName" value="#{bundle.NomeEquipamento_Title}"/>
            <h:inputText value="#{materialController.selected.equipmentName}" class="w_130" id="equipmentName" required="false" validatorMessage="#{bundle.NomeEquipamento_Title} inválido."/>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h:outputLabel for="channelCode" value="#{bundle.CodigoCanal_Title}"/>
            <h:inputText value="#{materialController.selected.channelCode}" class="w_80" id="channelCode" required="false" validatorMessage="#{bundle.CodigoCanal_Title} inválido."/>
        </li>
        <li><h:commandButton type="reset" class="bt_limpar button29" style="margin-top:13px;"><span class="screen_reader_text">Limpar</span></h:commandButton></li>
        <li><h:commandLink action="#{materialController.pesquisa}" class="bt_pesquisar button29" style="margin-top:13px;" immediate="true"><span class="screen_reader_text">Pesquisar</span></h:commandLink></li>
    </ul>
</h:form>
```

This is my DTO with the two attributes "equipmentName" and "channelCode":

```
public class SearchCommercialsDTO implements Serializable{

    private String equipmentName;
    private Integer channelCode;

   /**
    * Default constructor
    */
    public SearchCommercialsDTO() {}

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param equipmentName
     * @param channelCode 
     */
    public SearchCommercialsDTO(String equipmentName, Integer channelCode) {
        this.equipmentName = equipmentName;
        this.channelCode = channelCode;
    }
    public String getEquipmentName() {
        return equipmentName;
    }

    public void setEquipmentName(String equipmentName) {
        this.equipmentName = equipmentName;
    }

    public Integer getChannelCode() {
        return channelCode;
    }

    public void setChannelCode(Integer channelCode) {
        this.channelCode = channelCode;
    }
}
```

And this is my manadgedbean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "materialController")
@SessionScoped
public class MaterialController implements Serializable {

    private SearchCommercialsDTO current;
    private int selectedItemIndex;

    public MaterialController() {
    }

    public SearchCommercialsDTO getSelected() {
        if (current == null) {
            current = new SearchCommercialsDTO();
            selectedItemIndex = -1;
        }
        return current;
    }

    public String pesquisa() {
        try{
            getFacade().find(current);
            JsfHelper.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PesquisaRealizada"));
            return preparaPesquisa();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JsfHelper.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

When I click in "Pesquisar" button, the post is made but the "SearchCommercialsDTO" attribute "current" is passed with all the attributes values "null", even if I type something in the input text fields.

What is missing in my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try remove immediate="true" from your commandLink

Comment: You are welcome @GabrielBombardi ,the problem was immediate when set to true it will escape jsf validation and set values to null

Comment: Oh... what a mistake! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `getSelectedMethod()`.

Add attribute `selected` to `ManagedBean`

```
private SearchCommercialsDTO selected;
// getter and setter for selected attribute
```

Move actual `getSelectedMethod()` body to `actionListener`

```
public void getSelectedActionListener(ActionEvent e) {
    if (current == null) {
        current = new SearchCommercialsDTO();
        selectedItemIndex = -1;
    }
}
```

Add this code to your view

```
<h:commandLink action="#{materialController.pesquisa}" actionListener="#{materialController.selectedActionListener}" ...>...</h:commandLink></li>
```

After those changes `actionListener` will be fired up before `action`.

Comment: I think its a good solution too, but I don't know if it will change the actual process that is working on my code.
What's the problem of the action fire up before actionListener?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: `actionListener` will prepare data for the main `action` and getter/setter for `selected` argument will only set/return data. In my opinion it will be more clear.